# How can i choose the Max Decision number of two different column?

Tags: sql, ms-access

The same client can have multiple decision numbers, I need to choose the max of multiple the decision number. Please help.

sample data

```
CNO    DNO
1       1
1       2
3       3
```

Comment: add some datas to your question if you want us to go in the right direction

Comment: CNO : 1 Decno: 1 ; CNO:1 Decno:2 ; CNO:3 Decno:3. My query shall give CNO:3, Decno:3 from where clause. Thank You

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Perhaps you can add more details, to explain better the most important parts of your question and show a part of your data. Have a read of [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more information.

Comment: uk visa..
the info CNO u have provided is difficult to understand which one is column name and which one is the value,

Answer (score 0):

You can use window function like:

```
max(decisionNumber) over (partition by ClientName) as 'MAXofDecisionNumber'
```

Comment: This doesnt work I am sorry. This is how the content is in the DB.                 CNO : 1 Decno: 1 ; CNO:1 Decno:2 ; CNO:3 Decno:3. My query shall give CNO:3, Decno:3 from where clause. Thank You

Comment: If you could provide some sample data in tabular form and your desired output, it would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DECNO,MAX(CNO) FROM TABLE1 GROUP BY DECNO
```

FOR BOTH MAX

```
SELECT DECNO,MAX(CNO) FROM TABLE1
WHERE DECNO = (SELECT MAX(DECNO) FROM TABLE1)
GROUP BY DECNO
```

Live Demo

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3cdd0/3